# Unable to install Ubuntu 12.04 - Acer Aspire 5750G

Tags: dual-boot, mbr

I have a Acer Aspire 5750G. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 - 64 bit as a dual boot onto my C: Drive using wubi (or whatever its called) but I couldn't load windows after it and formatted my laptop (later finding out that I could have just rearranged by MBR). I am now trying to install it to a partition (U: drive)  and when I try to install Ubuntu it glitches out and says unable to download/load some file. I have tried downloading whole ISO and burning containing file to disk along with trying just the iso and using wubi and no matter what I do it won't install and I always get the same error. I am unable to boot using a disk (not sure if its just a issue with my laptop or because its a rental from Radio Rentals) but I have tried many other work arounds

Comment: You are unable to boot using a disk? A Compact one or ...?

Comment: i cant install using a CD, or using wubi, when i go to select boot device and select DVD drive it skips it and just loads windows so i have to use wubi to install which doesnt work either

Comment: I have heard that you have to install Windows first when you do dual instillations?

Comment: I don't know if you checked your CD's checksum, MD5 but, may be a corrupted CD? "It skips" doesn't seemed a bug or Error to me. Check your download and CD/DVD please. And sure, you are not forced to WUBI. Follow my answer please.

Comment: i have managed to get it to work once but says is unable to run C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /set {cf09be72-552c-11e0-9f2d-cc1ee84230bf} device partition=U:

Comment: and i tried running it myself and wouldnt work i used a third party software to run a script to fix it and when ubuntu come up in boot menu i launched it and it was in something caled grubcmd or something

Comment: Yes @jacinta but he is already installing Windows first.

Comment: You are sure about the image right?

Comment: iv downloaded 2 copies of each (a 32 bit and 64 bit version) from the ubuntu site and one of each via a torrent site

Comment: What about VM (my last question)

Comment: yea i already have windows installed and iv reinstalled earlier today and when i went to redo ubuntu the issues popped up

Comment: 19 minutes left on install on my vmware

Comment: my copy of Ubuntu 12.04 runs on vmware perfectly :)

Comment: It's nice to hear that. But I really want to hear the reason from you if you find out. Just doesn't start to install. With no errors or strange behaviors... By the way. That started to turn a chat. Have a nice day.

Comment: it installs gets all the way to the last ten seconds and fails at C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit /set {cf09be72-552c-11e0-9f2d-cc1ee84230bf} device partition=U:

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Virtual Machine, and try to install it using your downloaded image, CD again.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ might help. If you can't install using VM, you have a bad download (and/or CD). If you can, mind using it or forcing WUBI to install again.

Comment: im currently installing on vmware now :) it iv had it running once on my laptop but couldnt boot into windows so did a factory restore and now it wont reinstall, 30 mins remaining on the vmware install

Answer (score 0):

I found [a solution here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/installation/187209-no-way-install-linux-acer-aspire-5750g.html).

In the BIOS, replace graphic mode by 'integrated' (by default it's 'switcable). This works well on my machine.